# c# starting new column without duplcated data --printing from dataGridView

Tags: c#, loops, printing, datagridview

I try to print datas from a dataGridView and i have a problem:
I try to check the lenght of the filled up datas and if it is longer then 800 then i try to take it an other column. If i start the new column then the first column last data is the same like the new column first data.

How can i continue writing datas without duplication?

Code:

```
       if (height <= 800)
            {

                height += 75;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(60, height));


                Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.ugro;
                Image newImage = bmp;

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 20, height + 20, 100, 100);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2), 10, height - 20, 300, 150);


                height += 75;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Code_39 3_0", 36), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(  150, height));


            }





            if (height > 800)
            {

                Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.ugro;
                Image newImage = bmp;
                int width = 400;

                height1 += 75;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(width + 60, height1));


                e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, width + 20, height1 + 20, 100, 100);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2), width + 10, height1 - 20, 300, 150);


                height1 += 75;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Code_39 3_0", 36), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(width + 150, height1));


            }
```

I tried to count the loops but the result was the same!

Example for bad result:

```
col1   col2
----------
1       3

2       4

3       5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting doubles because you execute the first `if` statement then you add values to the `height` variable then by the point the `height` variable reaches the second `if` statement it may be higher than 800 so it gets inside the second `if` an it prints again.

So you have two solutions.

**Solution 1:**
    Move the second `if (height > 800) {...}` statement before the first `if (height <= 800) {...}` statement.

**Solution 2:**
    Add a local variable so the `height` variable doesn't get affected by the addition like this:

```
if (height <= 800)
{
    int printHeight = height;
    printHeight += 75;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(60, printHeight));


    Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.ugro;
    Image newImage = bmp;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 20, printHeight + 20, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2), 10, printHeight - 20, 300, 150);


    printHeight += 75;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Code_39 3_0", 36), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(  150, printHeight));


}


if (height > 800)
{

    Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.ugro;
    Image newImage = bmp;
    int width = 400;

    height1 += 75;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(width + 60, height1));


    e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, width + 20, height1 + 20, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2), width + 10, height1 - 20, 300, 150);


    height1 += 75;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(checkedRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString(), new Font("Code_39 3_0", 36), new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ForeColor), new Point(width + 150, height1));


}
```